# WebBrowser Control .Document/.DocumentText timing out?

Tags: c#, html, .net-4.0, webbrowser-control

I need access to the HTML source from a website for a program that I am writing using a web browser control. The program itself will be manipulating things based on the HTML but I'm having a problem.
Based on something that I had seen I saw that allowing about 100 MS for the control to update the text should be enough.

I have a timer event tied to trigger to save the `WebBrowser.Document`/`WebBrowser.DocumentText` to a globally accessible doc file, but the problem I am running into is that there is a Specified Cast Not Valid exception being thrown. When I try to look at what is inside the DocumentText property, nothing comes up. Setting a watch says that the function evaluation has been disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out.

For now I'm just trying to print the `DocumentText` using the `Console.WriteLine` function but even that's not working.

I guess in summation, I have no idea what I'm doing. Can someone direct me to a resolution or a solution that will achieve the results I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/642f59c5-84f1-4945-90d3-220592ace5f1

Specifically, the solution is to add an event handler to the `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event like so:

```
    void Browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Browser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            doc = Browser.Document;
    }
```

I believe that the crux is in the if statement. If that is true the document is accessible so it can probably be put anywhere (and should be considering dealing with it in that event handler means that unless you store everything in an array or list it's going to be overwritten every time you navigate to a new page).